# Does UIWindow randomly remove its subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

The reason I ask is because I was doing the following in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    PageViewController *pageViewController = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [pageViewController release];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But, when I tried to scroll the `pageView`, whose controller implements the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, I got an error like:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f42a80
```

When I took out `[pageViewController release];`, this error went away. This is weird to me because `window` should retain ... OH GOD!!! duh... it retains the `pageViewController`'s view, not the `pageViewController`.

I get it now why it's wrong to release `pageViewController`. Silly me... I think it's time for a break.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you figured this part out, but the answer to your question is no, UIWindow does not randomly remove its subview AFAIK. In this case, it's retaining `pageViewController.view` not `pageViewController`. So, you shouldn't release `pageViewController` nor should you release `pageViewController.view` because `pageViewController.view` will automatically get released when `pageViewController` is released. I don't see where you are releasing `pageViewController`. I recommend making it an ivar of the `AppDelegate` and then releasing it in the `AppDelegate`'s `dealloc` method, as you've probably done with `window`. The `dealloc` method never gets called, so `pageViewController` (and `window`) will never explicitly get `released` anyway, but making `pageViewController` an ivar is better style IMHO. Either way, I'll bet they get cleaned up when the application terminates.

Comment: Are you answering your own question as if you are talking to someone else? Haha.

Comment: Probably someone stole his account and answered his question.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale, your schizophrenic response to yourself is quite bizarre.